# Norm of multiplication and multiplication of norms

Tags: matrices, inequality, vectors, normed-spaces

It is well known that $\|u \cdot v \|_2 \le  \|u \|_2  \cdot \| v \|_2 $ 
for all $u, v \in \mathbb{R}^d$.

Is the following true for all $p \in \mathbb{R}$:

$$\|u \cdot v \|_p \le  \|u \|_p  \cdot \| v \|_p$$
for all $u, v \in \mathbb{R}^d$?

Comment: A common restriction is to impose $p \ge 1$ or at least $p>0$.

Comment: To the suggesting editor: Sorry for the override on the edit; it was non-intentional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not true. Take $p=3$ and $u=v = (1,1)$.

Then the right side is $2$, while the left-side is $2^{1/3}2^{1/3}$.

For a result somewhat in that direction see [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality).